# OpenCV "getOptimalNewCameraMatrix" behaving differently on Linux/ARM and Windows

Tags: python, opencv

I am using OpenCV to undistort images. The Code works fine on a Windows machine (Win 10, Conda environment opencv-version 3.4.) but results in a 0x0px image on a Raspberry Pi 4b (opencv-version 4.3.0.38). The reason seems to be, that getOptimalNewCameraMatrix returns a different Matrix and Roi on the Pi

As far as i'm concerned there should not be a different output for the same inputs depending on the OS/Architecture. I'm kind of lost and appreciate any type of input!

(somewhat)MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

#Image Dimensions
w=1024
h=768

#Parameters for undistortion
dist=np.array([[-2.85565904e-01, 1.12953316e-01, -1.99828374e-05, 1.23181460e-03, -2.40348722e-02]])
mtx =np.array([[500.94118521, 0., 557.7440342],[0., 500.13379004, 378.9970866],[0., 0., 1.]])
        
newcameramtx, roi=cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx,dist,(w,h),1,(w,h))

print(newcameramtx)
```

Output on Windows 10 Conda environement (yields usefull undistortion)

```
[[354.12069702   0.         534.00911997]
 [  0.         323.64080811 370.0690567 ]
 [  0.           0.           1.        ]]
```

Output on a raspberry pi 4 B

```
[[ 25.96581841   0.         988.14487751]
 [  0.          31.46662331  35.98070241]
 [  0.           0.           1.        ]]
```

Comment: When I run your code on Windows, I consistently get the same output as you get on the RPi (with 31.4 in the middle) with OpenCV 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4.3, 4.0 and 4.1. Then on the same platform, I get the output you got on windows (with 323.6 in the middle) for OpenCV 4.2, 4.3, 4.4 and 4.5. So, doesn't look like a platform difference here, but rather something that changed in the implementation between 4.1 and 4.2. What I don't understand is that on your side it's exactly opposite, as you claim the first is from 3.4 and second from 4.3 -- odd... maybe mistake in your post?

Comment: @Micka I think that's in the second sentence. But for some reason I get the opposite behaviour, see above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there was a bug about `getOptimalNewCameraMatrix()` in old version OpenCV, and it was fixed in Version **3.4.9** as well as **4.2.0** (they were both released in 2019.12).

That is to say, if you are using OpenCV3 before 3.4.9 or OpenCV4 before 4.2.0, the function `getOptimalNewCameraMatrix()` may get incorrect result. It's not about platforms.

For reference:

- [#15953: Bugs in stereoRectify (cvStereoRectify), initCameraMatrix2D (cvInitIntrinsicParams2D), getOptimalNewCameraMatrix (cvGetOptimalNewCameraMatrix)](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15953)
- [#16024: calib3d: revert stereoRectify() changes from PRs: 6836, 6972, 6955](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/16024)